# interop.acropdflib.dll does not work properly if different Adobe Products are installed and license is missing

Tags: c#, adobe, com-interop

I have a C# Application using interop.acropdflib for viewing PDF files.
It is working fine in general, but if a PC has Adobe Reader and Adobe Pro installed and the current user is missing the Adobe Pro license, then viewing the PDF file does not work reliably.
Suspicious is, that it is sometimes working and sometimes not.
If the first PDF file gets successfully viewed after the start of the application, it works with all the files for the rest of the time the application is running. If the Application does not manage to view the first PDF file it won't for any other until the application is closed.
Strangely, changing the standard application for pdf files does increase the probability of successfully viewing the PDF file from about 25 % - 40 % to 60 % - 70 %.
Sometimes at the start of the Application error messages appear even if the PDF files get viewed successfully: "Problem with Adobe Acrobat/Reader. If the program is running, close and start again. (103:103)" or "At the call of the COM component an HRESULT E_FAIL error was returned" *translated to English

I guess it is related to the missing license as adobe pro is closing as well if the license is missing. It seems, that Adobe either chooses between Reader and Pro library when starting with interop.acropdflib or does not always manage to check the license in time or sometimes skips checking the license.

I tried to register both interob.acropdflib.dll and AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll via RegAsm.exe /tlb /codebase which seems to change nothing according to my issue.

I need to know if there are any options to force the wrapper to rely on Adobe Reader where no license is necessary.